# Convert stream to String... (3 dot)

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream

How to convert a stream to String...(3 dot)
I have a method `mapToSomeObj(String... args)`
How do I pass Stream object into mapToSomeObj method.
When I pass `Obj.stream().map(a->a.getVal()).toArray()` I get [string1, string2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3 dots stand for [Vararg declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) which is compiled to an array, making `mapToSomeObj(String...)` method signature the same as `mapToSomeObj(String[])` signature.

Assuming `a.getVal()` returns a `String` your approach should work:

```
String[] arr = Obj.stream().map(a::getVal).toArray(String[]::new);
mapToSomeObj(arr);
```

Comment: `a -> a.getVal()` could be replaced by `a::getVal`.